# Images not showing in gallery

Tags: java, android

I am working on the Whats'up status saver app. The status images are showing in the file manager but are not showing in the gallery.

Here is my code

```
public void downlaodImage(StatusModel statusModel) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(MyContanst.APP_DIRECTORY);
        if (!file.exists()){
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        File destFile = new File(file+ File.separator+statusModel.getTitle());
        if (destFile.exists()){
            destFile.delete();
        }

        copyFile(statusModel.getPath(), destFile);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(destFile));
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);


    }

    private void copyFile(String file, File destFile) throws IOException {
        if (!destFile.getParentFile().exists()){
            destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }

        if (!destFile.exists()){
            destFile.createNewFile();
        }

        FileChannel src = null;
        FileChannel dst = null;

        src = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
        dst = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());

         src.close();
         dst.close();
    }
```

What I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not checking the return value of mkdirs() and delete(). So you are not acting accordingly to those values.

Comment: Further you do not have to call createNewFile() as the FileOutputStream will create the file. Remove that statement. Also here you did not check return value.

Comment: So only three things done wrong ;-).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call a broadcast to tell Android OS that you have added an Image or Video

So after download image/video just call below method will show your image/video in to gallery.

```
public  void scanMedia(File f, String type) {
        if (SDK_INT >= 19) {
            if (type.equals("video/*")) {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, f.getAbsolutePath());
                values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, type);
                values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
                try{
                    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                    retriever.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(f.getAbsolutePath()));
                    String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
                    long timeInMillisec = Long.parseLong(time);
                    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION, timeInMillisec);
                    retriever.release();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION, 0);
                }

                context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            }else if(type.equals("image/*")){
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, f.getAbsolutePath());
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, type);
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
                context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            }

        } else {
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(f)));
        }
    }
```

Happy Coding.